# Change value of a json file with another in a loop in python

Tags: python

I want to replace values from a list in another list (two json files) with the same ids. I created two loops but it's taking a very long time to do so (I have 10 000 items in each file). How can I reduce it ?

The files:

```
[{
   "objectid": 1,
   "cote": {
       "cote_2020": {
          "cote_2020_eu": {
          "cote_2020_base_eu": null,
          "cote_2020_excp_eu": null,
          "cote_2020_be_eu": null,
          "cote_2020_me_eu": null
    }
  },
  {
   "objectid": 2,
   "cote": {
       "cote_2020": {
          "cote_2020_eu": {
          "cote_2020_base_eu": null,
          "cote_2020_excp_eu": null,
          "cote_2020_be_eu": null,
          "cote_2020_me_eu": null
    }
  }]
```

The second file (with values):

```
[{
   "objectid": 1,
   "cote": {
       "cote_2020": {
          "cote_2020_eu": {
          "cote_2020_base_eu": 10000,
          "cote_2020_excp_eu": 11000,
          "cote_2020_be_eu": 9000,
          "cote_2020_me_eu": 8000
    }
  },
  {
   "objectid": 2,
   "cote": {
       "cote_2020": {
          "cote_2020_eu": {
          "cote_2020_base_eu": 20000,
          "cote_2020_excp_eu": 22000,
          "cote_2020_be_eu": 19000,
          "cote_2020_me_eu": 18000
    }
  }]
```

My code:

```
or item_complete in data_complete:
complete_id = item_complete["objectID"]
complete_cote_2020_base_eu = item_complete["cote"]["cote_2020"]["cote_2020_eu"]["cote_2020_base_eu"]
complete_cote_2020_excp_eu = item_complete["cote"]["cote_2020"]["cote_2020_eu"]["cote_2020_excp_eu"]
complete_cote_2020_be_eu = item_complete["cote"]["cote_2020"]["cote_2020_eu"]["cote_2020_be_eu"]
complete_cote_2020_me_eu = item_complete["cote"]["cote_2020"]["cote_2020_eu"]["cote_2020_me_eu"]

for item_data, item_scraped in data, data_scraped:
    data_id = item_data["objectID"]
    scraped_id = item_data["objectID"]
    #for item_scraped in data_scraped:
    if complete_id == data_id and complete_cote_2020_base_eu is not None:
        #eu
        item_data["cote"]["cote_2020"]["cote_2020_eu"]["cote_2020_base_eu"] = complete_cote_2020_base_eu
        item_data["cote"]["cote_2020"]["cote_2020_eu"]["cote_2020_excp_eu"] = complete_cote_2020_excp_eu
        item_data["cote"]["cote_2020"]["cote_2020_eu"]["cote_2020_be_eu"] = complete_cote_2020_be_eu
        item_data["cote"]["cote_2020"]["cote_2020_eu"]["cote_2020_me_eu"] = complete_cote_2020_me_eu
```

I have an `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. When I create a second for loop, it take a very long times (several minutes at least).

I want the first file to have the second files values.

Comment: If you want to copy all nested items, why don't you just copy the outer items, eg 'cote_2020' or even 'cote'? Time will reduce significantly

Comment: I don't know I didn't think of that...

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood for-loops in python:

```py
for item_data, item_scraped in data, data_scraped:
```

As far as i can see, `data` and `data_scraped` are two lists / arrays with more than two elements. The above is equivalent to:

```py
for item_data, item_scraped in [data, data_scraped]:
```

Your for loop will run twice : once it will work on `data`, and once on `data_scraped`. For each list element, it tries to extract two elements (`item_data` and `item_scraped`). But as there are more than two items in each list, it fails to do that. To iterate over both lists together, you must `zip()` them together:

```py
for item_data, item_scraped in zip(data, data_scraped):
```

Here is an example of what zip does:

```py
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
words = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]
for number, word in zip(numbers, words):
    print(number, word)
```

Output:

```
1 one
2 two
3 three
4 four
5 five
6 six
7 seven
8 eight
9 nine
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy all nested items, you could just copy the outer items, eg 'cote_2020' or even 'cote' Time will reduce significantly. The following should work (old_dict is your dict with values and new_dict is the dict with nulls):

```
for i in range(len(new_dict)):
    ref=[k for k in old_dict if k['objectid']==new_dict[i]['objectid']][0] 
    new_dict[i]['cote']=ref['cote']
```